# API works on browser with Request shown in Network, but not from Angular2

Tags: angular, api, cross-domain, http-status-code-400

I'm trying to call API using Angular 2, but it sends CORS error. However, If I try to call the same API from http://www.webtoolkitonline.com/javascript-tester.html (a Javascript Tester) or http://hurl.it, then it executes it correctly.

I've tried adding headers from Client side also.

My Angular Code is as below

```
   private _apiCountryUrl = 'http://52.179.4.123/smvs/index.jsp?json={"COUNTRY":[{"ACTION":"SELECT"}]}';

    getTotalCountry() : Observable<ICountry[]> {
        let headersNew = new HttpHeaders();
        headersNew.append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
        headersNew.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET');
        headersNew.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');


        return this._http.get<ICountry[]>(this._apiCountryUrl, {headers: headersNew})
        .do(data => console.log('Country' + JSON.stringify(data)))
        .catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

When API is called, I'm getting output as below.

[image]

If I write code as below

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: 'http://52.179.4.123/smvs/index.jsp?json=%7B%22COUNTRY%22%3A%5B%7B%22ACTION%22%3A%22SELECT%22%7D%5D%7D',
          success: function(res) {
            alert(res);
          },
          error: function(error) {
            alert("error!" + JSON.stringify(error));
          }
        });
    });
```

The above code works correct with http://www.webtoolkitonline.com/javascript-tester.html the but same API is not called from Angular2. If it's server side error then it should not even called when jQUery request is done.

[image]

Comment: @echonax, my question is that why it allowed from other websites like javascript tester or hurl.it

Comment: They might be making https requests or the server may have allowed them to make the calls